# Understanding output of runWriter (return 3 :: Writer String Int)

Tags: haskell

I'm reading http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more and there's this example:

```
instance (Monoid w) => Monad (Writer w) where  
    return x = Writer (x, mempty)  
    (Writer (x,v)) >>= f = let (Writer (y, v')) = f x in Writer (y, v `mappend` v')
```

then it does the following evaluation:

```
ghci> runWriter (return 3 :: Writer String Int)  
(3,"")
```

For me, `return 3`, when constrained to be of type `Writer String Int` should give `("3", 0)` (I don't know why I put 0, but I guess `mempty` for `Int` should be 0. I also don't understand `mempty` very well.

Then, when we run runRead into `return 3`, we should get

```
(3, "")
```

and I've put 3 as number because it must be a number because runReader reverts the types.

Comment: MTL 2.0.0.0 changed how `Writer` is implemented under the hood. It now uses monad transformers instead of a simple tuple, and LYAH never updated to take that into account.

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: Notice that `Writer` has two type parameters: the first is for the monoidal accumulator (a `String` in your example) and the second is the one that changes with `fmap`/`>>=` operations (an `Int` in `return 3`). The "internal tuple" of `Writer String Int` has type `(Int,String)`. `return` is using the `mempty` of `String`, not of `Int`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the definition given on that page of the `Writer` type:

```
newtype Writer w a = Writer { runWriter :: (a, w) }
```

See the order of `a` and `w` on both sides of that equation? See how the tuple order is different from the order of parameters to the type?

This means that a value of type `Writer String Int` will be a tuple of type `(Int, String)` wrapped in the `Writer` constructor.

`runWriter` is just a fancy name for "unwrap the `Writer` constructor".